# I can't get router and switches configured properly for my home office network

Tags: router, home-networking, ethernet, switch, wiring

I recently built a new detached garage, with an office above.  As such I had it tied into my existing home Ethernet wiring.  The Ethernet signal is coming into the garage just fine, but I cannot get my network configured the way I want because of problems trying to link the various router/switch devices.

**Here is my current state:**

[image]

**Here is my desired future state:**

[image]

I can't get my future state to work.  I'm not sure if I'm using incompatible switches or some other issue - I tried the future state with some 4 port switches from Best Buy but had no luck.  I resorted to setting up the current state so I could operate.

What's the best way to get my future state working?  Is this possible with my current configuration, and if not, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the way you have it patched.  I wonder if there is anything wrong with any of your jack wiring.  In your future config, can you connect a computer directly to the switch, does it work?  Do you know if your switches are self sensing? Meaning they can determine what type of equipment is connected to them, can automatically connect two switches together and the link light shows.  Do you have link on all ports which are connected to a computer or another switch?

Comment: Great diagrams and great answer...  I once was troubleshooting a far simpler network scenario and I almost pulled my hair out until I considered the network cable running through the wall as the culprit.  Once I bypassed that, I got to the bottom of the problem and fixed the issue at hand...  What you cannot see can often deceive you. ;--)  If there is anything I have learned from troubleshooting even modestly complicated networks it's the KISS technique: Keep it Simple Simon.

Comment: indeed.  i'd plug a laptop or other computer directly into the linksys 8-port switch (to make sure that works) then directly into each of the jacks (to make sure those work) and finally into the switches.  Troubleshooting 101: check one thing at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  It's been a while since I've tried to troubleshoot the whole thing.  Initially I did try some trouble shooting, but kept hitting brick walls.  I just decided to see if the switch is self sensing (per Brettski's suggestion) and noticed that they're not switches, they're hubs.  Dynex 4 port hubs.  Could that be a problem?  Should I go get some 4 port switches?

Comment: Update - I got it to work.  It's all about the uplink port.  I went ahead and decided to ditch the Dynex hubs and buy 3 Linksys workgroup switches (EZKS55W).  The trick is that when you're connecting to another router or switch, you have to connect the uplink port on the newly added switch to an open port on the older router or switch.  This may seem pretty obvious, but it just didn't click at first.  So after my ordeal, I recommend using same brand switches as the router, and be sure to use the uplink port.  Good luck to anyone else having the same problem.

Comment: Your newer switches usually don't have uplink ports because they automatic MDI/MDI-X configuration.  Back in the day we would use crossover cables, or an uplink port, if available, to connect two switches together.

Answer (score 1):

If they are "hubs" then they made need crossover cables.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem where I couldn't get the network to work with a network and the speed was slow. Basically I have a switch upstairs (5 port D-Link, printer is here too) and another in the basement (8 port D-Link). The basement also has the router.

When my basement switch was directly connected to my upstairs switch, the printer didn't work. After connecting my upstairs switch directly to the router (so the router now has two switches connected to it - 5 port and 8 port), the printer worked. My network speeds also increased with this configuration from 1Mbps to 5-10Mbps.

My suggestion would be to wire the router into your office and connect every switch directly to the router.